# Python- validate generated powerset

Tags: python

I want to validate generated combinations only based on data with in "< >".

I have an excel sheet consisting of all the possible combinations generated based on "<>" condition:
   Below is the sample of that:

```
    [<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[dress0]-C(D0)-lbr-]
    [<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[dress0]-C(D0)-lbr-]
    [NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[dress0]-C(D0)-lbr-]
    [NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[dress0]-C(D0)-lbr-]
```

I want to check if the generated combinations is valid or not.
   For example: for the above list the original string before generating combinations is below:

```
    <Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)--<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-
```

Kindly help me to find a generic method to validate all the powersets generated based on <>.

To give a simple example: 
    I have the below list1.

```
[<A><B>-CAT-DOG]
[NULL-<B>-CAT-DOG]
[<A>-NULL-CAT-DOG]
[NULL-NULL-CAT-DOG]
```

The list1 is all possible combination of:

```
<A><B>-CAT-DOG
```

I want to check if the above list1 is valid or not

Comment: You need to give us a clearer explanation of your problem since you appear to be using the term [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) in an unusual way. Also, it would be good if you posted some relevant code.

Comment: PM 2Ring thanks for the response. I have edited accordingly. And I am new to python, looking for ideas to implement this.

Comment: Generating powersets is pretty easy, and testing if a given set is a subset of another is very easy: there are built-in methods for that. The problem here is your obscure notation. Where does one item end and the next one begin?

Comment: What is the rule, that makes a "powerset" valid?  Have you accomplished importing your data to python?

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a lot clearer!

Comment: Evgeny Pogrebnyak For me the generated combinations is valid if it satisfies the powerset rule which i have explained in simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can build the desired combinations using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which generates the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of its iterable arguments. But first we need to split the input string up into its components. We can do that by first adding some extra spaces and then calling the `.split` method.

We can then transform each string in the list returned by `.split` into a tuple. Items enclosed by `<` and `>` get transformed into a 2-tuple containing the item and the `'NULL'` string, all other items become 1-tuples.

```
from itertools import product

def make_powerset(base):
    # Add some spaces to make splitting easier
    s = base.replace('-', ' ').replace('<', ' <').replace('>', '> ')

    # Convert items enclosed in <> into 2-tuples and make other items 1-tuples
    elements = [(u, 'NULL') if u.startswith('<') else (u,) for u in s.split()]

    # Create all the subsets by finding the Cartesian product of all the tuples
    return {'-'.join(t).replace('>-<', '><') for t in product(*elements)}

# Tests

# Make a powerset from base
base = '<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)--<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-'
powerset = make_powerset(base)
for t in powerset:
    print(t)
print()

# Test if the following data are in the powerset
data = (
    '<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-',
    '<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-',
    'NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-',
    'NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-',
    '<Pen(y)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr-',
)

for s in data:
    print(s, s.rstrip('-') in powerset)

print('\n', '- ' * 20, '\n')

# Make another powerset
for t in make_powerset('<A><B>-CAT-DOG<C>'):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr
NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr
<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr
NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr

<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr- True
<Pen(x)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr- True
NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-<jack(c)>-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr- True
NULL-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr- True
<Pen(y)>-C(A2)-C(60)-NULL-xy1-[address0]-C(D0)-lbr- False

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  

NULL-NULL-CAT-DOG-NULL
NULL-<B>-CAT-DOG-NULL
<A>-NULL-CAT-DOG-<C>
<A>-NULL-CAT-DOG-NULL
NULL-NULL-CAT-DOG-<C>
<A><B>-CAT-DOG-<C>
NULL-<B>-CAT-DOG-<C>
<A><B>-CAT-DOG-NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was of great help

Comment: @Perl I'm glad you like my answer, but you haven't actually accepted it yet.

Comment: COLDSPEED thank you dint know that, new to stack overflow.